# Windows 8.1 App Audio with Effects (NAudio or SharpDX)

Tags: c#, windows, audio, naudio, sharpdx

How can i load an Audio File from `FileOpenPicker` with `NAudio` or `SharpDX` and add an `Audio FX` like Flanger, Phaser, Echo, Gate, Bit Crusher.

```
FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wav");
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".m4a");
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wma");
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".aac");
StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my Solution for a FX Sound Effect on my Audio File.

### Play Sound

Before we can start, you need the following packages, that you get easily with NuGet-Package:

- SharpDX
- SharpDX.MediaFoundation
- SharpDX.XAudio2

C#

```
FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wav");
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".m4a");
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wma");
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".aac");
StorageFile audioFile = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

MediaManager.Startup();
XAudio2 xaudio2 = new XAudio2();
xaudio2.StartEngine();
MasteringVoice masteringVoice = new MasteringVoice(xaudio2);
AudioPlayer audioPlayer = new AudioPlayer(xaudio2, await audioFile.OpenReadAsync());
```

The AudioPlayer Class come from Alexandre Mutel https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/tree/master/Desktop/XAudio2/AudioPlayerApp
.
In the AudioPlayer Class you change the Constructor from:

```
public AudioPlayer(XAudio2 xaudio2, Stream audioStream)
```

To:

```
public AudioPlayer(XAudio2 xaudio2, IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType audioStream)
```

Now, you can control the Audio File with `audioPlayer.Play();` `audioPlayer.Stop();`

### Add Effect

You can add an Effect so:

```
SourceVoice sourceVoice = audioPlayer.SourceVoice;
Reverb reverb = new SharpDX.XAPO.Fx.Reverb();
EffectDescriptor effectDescriptor = new EffectDescriptor(reverb);
sourceVoice.SetEffectChain(effectDescriptor);
sourceVoice.EnableEffect(0);
```

Comment: you are missing xaudio2 reference in Reverb() constructor